# menu link for mobiles and tablets

Tags: html

I am new in web page design. I made a web site in html and css.  I did not use wordpress or any kind of canned web designing site.

This kind of code does not work in mobiles. This is part the code in my website.

```
   <nav> 
      <ul> 
      <li> <a href="Vspring.html"> Home </a></li>
      <li> <a href="flowers.html"> Flowers </a> </li>     
     </ul>

     </nav>
```

I researched, and the code that I see is this:

```
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
```

Can somebody tell me what "#" means?

What can I do to make my links suitable for tablets and mobiles?

Thank you in advance to anybody who can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<nav> 
  <ul> 
      <li> <a href="/Vspring.html"> Home </a></li>
      <li> <a href="/flowers.html"> Flowers </a> </li>     
 </ul>
</nav>
```

also add css

```
a {display:block;}
```

Comment: Brooke:  Thank you so much. I had something wrong with the display and the padding.  Your comment was and eye opener.  Thank you again.  Maria La O